# Why doesn't my BIOS recognize a bootable partition?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, arch-linux

I've been following an Arch Linux install guide and partitioned my hard drive using `fdisk`. I've selected the disklabel type `dos` and created three partitions. One of these partitions I've flagged as bootable. I then continued and completed the entire installation within that partition without errors. But now that I want to boot from this partition BIOS won't even list the partition as an option. Also, if I boot from the install USB stick, I'm not offered "boot existing OS" contrary to my expectation.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Does the machine have UEFI firmware or a traditional BIOS? See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide#Verify_the_boot_mode

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

You forgot to install a bootloader. Depending on *which* guide you're following, it ought to have instructions for either GRUB2 or Syslinux. (Since it told you to set the 'bootable' flag, I am guessing it's the latter.)

Reboot again into the USB stick, mount the partitions you've made so that you're able to `arch-chroot` into them, and follow the instructions for [Syslinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Syslinux) or [GRUB2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB), whichever you prefer.

(Note that after installing either of those, you still need to create `grub.cfg` using `grub-mkconfig`, or edit `syslinux.cfg` by hand.)

---

Long answer:

First of all, a regular BIOS does not boot partitions at all. It does not understand operating systems, partition tables, nor 'bootable' flags – this is the job of whatever bootloader is installed to the disk's boot sector (the MBR). In other words, the BIOS only boots the specified *disk* by running code from the MBR, and then your bootloader takes over.

If the disk was previously empty, it will have no MBR bootcode at all. You can install e.g. the Syslinux MBR bootcode – which understands the MBR partition table, follows the 'bootable' flag, and tries to run the partition's own bootcode.

But you probably didn't install any bootcode to the partition, either. So even though the partition has a filesystem with all the files required for Linux – kernel and all – there's still nothing that knows how to find and start that kernel file. Merely setting the 'bootable' flag is not enough to actually make it bootable, it's the equivalent to putting up traffic signs without there being a road.

(As a side note, the MBR bootcode doesn't have to care about the 'bootable' flag at all. For example, the more popular GRUB bootloader doesn't need it because its MBR bootcode already directly embeds the correct partition number.)

To install *everything* needed to go from BIOS to the Linux kernel, you need to follow the full bootloader installation procedure for either GRUB or Syslinux.

Comment: I did actually have GRUB installed. Fiddling with the machine some more, I managed to get it to recognize the bootable partition by disabling UEFI. I'm not exactly sure why that helped or whether this might have unintended consequences.

Comment: UEFI has a completely different boot mechanism. You followed a tutorial that assumes a traditional PC BIOS or at least UEFI with the "BIOS compatibility module" – which _used to be_ enabled by default, but many new computers no longer do so. (Intel has plans to completely remove it in a few years.)